# How to override a method that has an argument of type Literal?

Tags: python, types, overriding, literals

When I try to override a method that has an argument with `Literal` as its type hint, I get a RecursionError from the `overrides` module (see stack trace below). I'm not sure why this is happening, or if it is possible to override such methods.

edit: The `overrides` module I'm talking about is this third party module: github.com/mkorpela/overrides

Here is a toy example that reproduces my error:

```
from typing import Literal

from overrides import overrides


class Base:
    def foo(self, mode: Literal["train"]) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class Child(Base):
    @overrides
    def foo(self, mode: Literal["train"]) -> None:
        pass
```

Removing the `@overrides` decorator is a workaround since it doesn't change my code's behavior, but I would prefer to keep it if possible. My plan is to change the arg type to an Enum which is probably a better design decision anyway. But I'm curious why this combination of `@overrides` and `Literal` doesn't work.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model-autotraining/temp.py", line 12, in <module>
    class ChildModel(BaseClass):
  File "model-autotraining/temp.py", line 14, in ChildModel
    def foo(self, mode: Literal["train"]) -> None:
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/overrides/overrides.py", line 88, in overrides
    return _overrides(method, check_signature, check_at_runtime)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/overrides/overrides.py", line 114, in _overrides
    _validate_method(method, super_class, check_signature)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/overrides/overrides.py", line 135, in _validate_method
    ensure_signature_is_compatible(super_method, method, is_static)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/overrides/signature.py", line 94, in ensure_signature_is_compatible
    ensure_all_kwargs_defined_in_sub(
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/overrides/signature.py", line 153, in ensure_all_kwargs_defined_in_sub
    and not _issubtype(super_type_hints[name], sub_type_hints[name])
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/overrides/signature.py", line 42, in _issubtype
    return issubtype(left, right)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_utils/__init__.py", line 428, in issubtype
    return _is_normal_subtype(normalize(left), normalize(right), forward_refs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_utils/__init__.py", line 251, in normalize
    args = _normalize_args(args)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_utils/__init__.py", line 232, in _normalize_args
    return tuple(_normalize_args(type_) for type_ in tps)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_utils/__init__.py", line 232, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(_normalize_args(type_) for type_ in tps)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_utils/__init__.py", line 232, in _normalize_args
    return tuple(_normalize_args(type_) for type_ in tps)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_utils/__init__.py", line 232, in <genexpr>

... repeated many times ...

  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_utils/__init__.py", line 232, in _normalize_args
    return tuple(_normalize_args(type_) for type_ in tps)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_utils/__init__.py", line 232, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(_normalize_args(type_) for type_ in tps)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/site-packages/typing_utils/__init__.py", line 231, in _normalize_args
    if isinstance(tps, collections.abc.Sequence):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/abc.py", line 98, in __instancecheck__
    return _abc_instancecheck(cls, instance)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/worker/lib/python3.8/abc.py", line 102, in __subclasscheck__
    return _abc_subclasscheck(cls, subclass)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: "from the overrides module." Where exactly does this come from? It [does not appear to be a standard library module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). This looks like a bug in that third-party functionality, which should be reported as such.

Comment: You're right, it's a third party module: https://github.com/mkorpela/overrides. I will report this as bug to them. I'm not sure if it's just a bug, or if there is some more fundamental reason this code doesn't work.

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/mkorpela/overrides/issues/94

Comment: And the discussion there says it's actually a bug in `typing_utils`. https://github.com/bojiang/typing_utils/issues/10. There's a PR with a fix, but it hasn't been merged.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted in the comments, this behavior is a bug in the third party `overrides` module I'm using https://github.com/mkorpela/overrides). It is a known bug: https://github.com/mkorpela/overrides/issues/94

Answer (score 0):

Bug in the package is now fixed.